# ServletContext.getRealPath("pictures") returns tmp dir?? JBoss

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, seam

I made an app with seamgen  (also with gui)  and i created a folder "pictures" in the root of the application for storing profile images .

When i evaluate ServletContext.getRealPath("pictures") it returns a temporary dir.

> D:\Dizertatie\Java\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp\5c4o02s-hw5k2v-gj5pc3oq-1-gj632njx-al\RaceCatalog.war\pictures\1295555156562.jpg

I tried also with the generated img folder  and it is still the same thing.

How do I get the relative path

PS. I want to use

Comment: I forgot to mention that i get the servlet context from a seam compoent like this: ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext(); maybe it affects somehow ..

Comment: is your application deployed as exploded or not exploded war ?

Comment: yes it is exploded with seam gens generated ant script  (the "explode" target)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in a comment of yours - you need this in order to render images. It is wrong to use this method for that purpose.

`<h:graphicsImage>` uses relative path to the root of the application context by default. No extra steps needed.

As for the behaviour of JBoss in extracting the war file - it seems odd, but it does not violate the specification. It is free to extract unexploded war files wherever it likes.

**Update:** If this is about an exploded war (by you), then feel free to fire a bug. But it doesn't matter that much - you shouldn't store pictures in the webapp. Configure an external location and save them there. Otherwise you risk to loose your pictures on redeploy.

Comment: +1 "No extra steps needed". OP is overcomplicating the issue.

Comment: for displaying images everything works fine but how can i save the images as in tomcat? (it is an exploded archive)

Comment: thank you . This is for my school project  and i wanted to take the short path  :) . so I will store it in web.xml as a context parameter

Comment: indeed - a context param is a good option. School project or not - it should be made well. And it does not actually take much more effort to do it with a context param :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The behavior is correct. See javadoc for description of what getRealPath() method is supposed to do: [Read here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

I suspect that you are looking for a different method, but you haven't adequately described what kind of a path you hope to get.

Comment: I want to use <h:graphicImage value="/pictures#{user.profileImage}" , And i don't want to use absolute paths .. How can i do that ?

Comment: sorry, but I don't think it is correct. It should return the real path to where his "picture" dir is - in his webapp, not some randomly generated temp folder

Comment: I forgot to mention that i get the servlet context from a seam compoent like this: ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();       maybe it affects somehow ..

Comment: I don't think you are comprehending the point of this method. It is supposed to return exactly where the path in question is being served from. It is not possible to return a path to inside a war archive, so the API has a bail clause. You can return null and it would still be correct. As most app servers will explode a deployed app for a variety of performance reasons, returning path to that location represents the truth of the situation and is much better than null.

Comment: I have often seen frivolous specification interpretation by JBoss, so I now took a look at the servlet specification. Contrary to what I thought, it does not specify the exact behaviour of extracting war files. And although it sounds odd that a temp directory is used, rather than the more logical behaviour of tomcat, strictly speaking it does not violate the spec. (hence I removed my downvote). However, what the OP appears to be asking is a different thing, hence I add a new answer.

Comment: I used seamgen to generate the project and i alwais explode the archive  and it creates in the deploy directory of jboss RaceCatalog.war dir and no war  .. but it always gives me the temp path. In tomcat i could do this but here i can't ?

Answer (score -2):

```
private static String temp2Real(String temp) {
    temp = temp.replaceFirst("temp", "webapps");
    temp = temp.replaceFirst("\\d+\\-", "");
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.